# Python pytest warnings when running test

Tags: python, warnings, pytest

I have a `myfun.py` file with my functions.
And I have a `test_myfun.py` file with `pytest` tests.

When running `pytest test_myfun.py`, the tests themselves run without errors, but pytest gives warnings.

Any suggestions how to solve these warnings?

```
=============================== warnings summary ===============================
/home/rene/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/html5lib/_trie/_base.py:3
  /home/rene/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/html5lib/_trie/_base.py:3: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
    from collections import Mapping

/home/rene/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py:8
  /home/rene/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py:8: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
    from collections import MutableMapping

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
==================== 11 passed, 2 warnings in 7.47 seconds =====================
```

*Version info*:
- Python 3.7.3
- pytest 4.6.2

```
# packages in environment at /home/rene/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pytest                    4.6.2                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.3.0                    py37_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.3.2                    py37_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0  
pytest-runner             4.4                        py_0
```

Comment: those packages need to be updated, that's all. They're still compatible, but won't be anymore in 3.8 that's what the message says

Comment: Thanks, but I have the latest packages installed from Anaconda and still get these warnings.

Comment: yes, precisely because the authors didn't fix the warnings yet. When I said "updated" I meant "updated by someone who will fix the code", not someone using "pip" to upgrade, since the upgrade doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options.

1) Upgrade your packages, that is if the most recent versions of `html5lib` and `scrapy` have fixed these warnings.

2) Create a `pytest.ini` file in the root of your repo and give it these contents, which will make `pytest` ignore the `DeprecationWarning`

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

Comment: I'm interested by the second option (in my case, the most recent version of the package is generating the same warnings). However, isn't setting the `ignore::DeprecationWarning` option also silences those warnings if there are other deprecations coming from my code? That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: @htaidirt you may use `ignore:my regexp:DeprecationWarning` to filter only DeprecationWarnings that match the regex.